# File Deleted from Physical Device but Receiving EEXIST Error

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I have an app which creates a .zip file that contains .pdf and .jpgs. If the .zip file is deleted by the user on the physical device, it throws an error when the user goes to create another zip file using the same name because it says the file already exists. From my understanding, this is because the file data is still stored in the MediaStore even though it's no longer visible on the device or the file explorer. Is there a way to delete the MediaStore entry upon deletion in the file explorer - or, what is the best way to programattically handle this?

Below is my code that creates the .zip file. I've changed the fragment and variable names for privacy, otherwise the code is exactly the same.

```
private fun zipDocs(){
    val pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS  + "/Report/" + Fragment.name + " " + Fragment.report + " " + date + ".pdf")
    val picPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES  + "/" + Fragment.name + " " + Fragment.report + " " + date)
    val outDest = FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS  + "/" + Fragment.name+ " " + Fragment.report + " " + date + ".zip"))
    val out = ZipOutputStream(outDest)
    if(picPath.listFiles() != null ) {
        picPath.listFiles().forEach {
            var fi = FileInputStream(it)
            var origin = BufferedInputStream(fi)
            var entry = ZipEntry(it.name)
            try {
                out.putNextEntry(entry)
                origin.copyTo(out, 1024)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Cannot create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } finally {
                out.closeEntry()
                origin.close()
                fi.close()
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "No pictures found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    if(pdfPath != null ) {
        var fi = FileInputStream(pdfPath)
        var origin = BufferedInputStream(fi)
        var entry = ZipEntry(pdfPath.name)
        try {
            out.putNextEntry(entry)
            origin.copyTo(out, 1024)

        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException){
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Cannot create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } finally {
            out.closeEntry()
            origin.close()
            fi.close()
        }
    }
    out.close()
}
```

Comment: Edited - does that help you solve my issue?

Comment: No. Not at all. The solution was already known. Query the media store for your file. You will get an uri. Then use the delete() member on that uri. That is all as you dont need a file explorer to remove that file.